# VB - Complete reset of geckofx

Tags: vb.net, geckofx

I have a Webrowser wich running with the gecko engine in VB.
And I want to clean everything before start, like I can do it with CCleaner and firefox. So I wrote a batch file that delete the defaultprofile folder(../appdata/geckofx/) and then starts my .exe
Everything works fine but my question is if there is another place where xulrunner or geckofx store anything in another folder or is my solution already "completely clean"?
Added my batch code if somebody wants to use it:

```
rmdir /s /q "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Geckofx\"
cd %~dp0
start %1myprogram.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean everything:

```
        Dim CookieMan As nsICookieManager
        CookieMan = Xpcom.GetService(Of nsICookieManager)("@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1")
        CookieMan = Xpcom.QueryInterface(Of nsICookieManager)(CookieMan)
        CookieMan.RemoveAll()
```